# One Delphi package is falsely detected as depending from other package

Tags: delphi

Recently I developed and installed VlControls Delphi package with own components.

Now when any developer on any machine takes other, one year old, CmGUI package, which existed long before VlControls, and tries to build it, following window pops up:

> The following changes are necessary to make this package compatible with other installed packages.
> Choose OK to apply these changes and rebuild the package.
>
> Add VlControls.
> VlControls contains implicit unit(s) TeeBlockCanvas, TeeMesh, TeeBlockEditor, TeeBlockGallery, TeeBlockClasses, TeeWater, TeeBlocks, TeeMakerConst, TeeLoadError, TeeTarga, TeeGLSLShaders, TeeViewBlock, TeeCamera, TeeMakerControl, TeePlayMP3, TeeTextureSelector, TeeMakerEditor, TeeSelectProperty, TeeClipBlock, TeePointEditor, Tee3DSFormat, TeeFacesBlock, TeeObjFormat, TeeSubdivideMesh, TeePointItemEditor, TeeActionGallery, TeeSoundSelector, TeeMakerLibrary, TeeLoadBlock, TeeExtruded, TeeRoundRect, TeeMoveAnimation, TeeNumberAnimation, TeeExtrudedEditor, TeeActionAnimation, TeeBlockAnimations, TeeBlockReplacer, TeeHelix, TeeRain, TeeBlockFormat, TeePipe, TeeProperties, TeeDraw3DEditor, TeeKinematics, TeeColorPalette, TeeRevolutionEditor, TeeRevolution, TeeAnimationGallery, VCLTee.TeeAnimateEditor, TeeTerrain, TeeEdgeStyle, TeeStairs, TeeChartBlock3DEditor, TeeChartBlock, TeeChart3D.

I do not know why this happens, because both packages are completely independent from each other. There are no files in CmGUI which contain "VlControls" string. What both packages have in common, are Tee chart components.

This happens only to this CmGUI package and other old packages are intact.

What could it be?

I am using Delphi 10.

**CmGUI.dpk:**

```js
package CmGUI;

{$R *.res}
{$IFDEF IMPLICITBUILDING This IFDEF should not be used by users}
{$ALIGN 8}
{$ASSERTIONS OFF}
{$BOOLEVAL OFF}
{$DEBUGINFO ON}
{$EXTENDEDSYNTAX ON}
{$IMPORTEDDATA ON}
{$IOCHECKS OFF}
{$LOCALSYMBOLS ON}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}
{$OPENSTRINGS ON}
{$OPTIMIZATION OFF}
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}
{$REFERENCEINFO OFF}
{$SAFEDIVIDE OFF}
{$STACKFRAMES ON}
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$VARSTRINGCHECKS ON}
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
{$MINENUMSIZE 1}
{$IMAGEBASE $400000}
{$DEFINE DEBUG}
{$ENDIF IMPLICITBUILDING}
{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}

requires
  rtl,
  vcl,
  vclx,
  dbrtl,
  adortl,
  tee923,
  designide,
  vclactnband,
  dclstd,
  OurPackageNumber1,
  OurPackageNumber2,
  vcltouch,
  NxCommonRun_d10,
  NxGridRun_d10,
  TeePro923,
  TeeUI923,
  TeeImage923,
  TeeGL923,
  VclSmp,
  vclFireDAC,
  FireDACIBDriver,
  FireDACPgDriver,
  IndyProtocols,
  NxCollectionRun_d10;

contains
  //Here come units from this package only. No external units are included.

end.
```

**VlControls.dpk:**

```js
package VlControls;

{$R *.res}
{$IFDEF IMPLICITBUILDING This IFDEF should not be used by users}
{$ALIGN 8}
{$ASSERTIONS ON}
{$BOOLEVAL OFF}
{$DEBUGINFO OFF}
{$EXTENDEDSYNTAX ON}
{$IMPORTEDDATA ON}
{$IOCHECKS ON}
{$LOCALSYMBOLS OFF}
{$LONGSTRINGS ON}
{$OPENSTRINGS ON}
{$OPTIMIZATION ON}
{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF}
{$REFERENCEINFO OFF}
{$SAFEDIVIDE OFF}
{$STACKFRAMES OFF}
{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF}
{$VARSTRINGCHECKS ON}
{$WRITEABLECONST OFF}
{$MINENUMSIZE 1}
{$IMAGEBASE $400000}
{$DEFINE RELEASE}
{$ENDIF IMPLICITBUILDING}
{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}

requires
  rtl,
  vcl,
  vclimg,
  vclx,
  TeePro923,
  TeeUI923,
  Tee923,
  DesignIDE,
  TeeImage923,
  TeeGL923,
  dbrtl,
  FireDAC,
  FireDACCommonDriver,
  FireDACCommon,
  IndySystem,
  IndyCore;

contains
  //Here come units from this package only. No external units are included.

end.
```

**Update**

Ok, I looked closely at my package and handled all warnings it displayed at compile time. Now the `contains` section has following units:

```js
TeeBlockCanvas,
TeeChart3D,
TeeChartBlock3DEditor,
TeeAnimationGallery,
TeeColorPalette,
TeeDraw3DEditor,
TeeProperties,
TeeBlockReplacer,
TeeEdgeStyle,
TeeLoadBlock,
TeeSoundSelector,
TeeActionGallery,
TeeMakerLibrary,
TeeMakerControl,
TeeCamera,
TeePointItemEditor,
TeeSelectProperty,
TeeTextureSelector,
TeeBlockFormat,
TeeSubdivideMesh,
TeePointEditor,
TeeGLSLShaders,
TeeLoadError,
TeeChartBlock,
TeeMesh,
TeeTerrain,
TeeMakerEditor,
TeeClipBlock,
TeeMoveAnimation,
TeeActionAnimation,
TeeBlockAnimations,
TeeNumberAnimation,
TeeKinematics,
TeeBlockEditor,
TeeBlockGallery,
TeeBlockClasses,
TeeViewBlock,
TeeExtrudedEditor,
TeeHelix,
TeeRevolution,
TeeRevolutionEditor,
TeeStairs,
TeeRain,
TeeWater,
VCLTee.TeeAnimateEditor,
TeePlayMP3,
Tee3DSFormat,
TeeObjFormat,
TeeFacesBlock,
TeePipe,
TeeExtruded,
TeeRoundRect,
TeeBlocks,
TeeMakerConst,
TeeTarga;
```

As I understand, next step would be to look at each unit and find out which package it belongs to and then add package name to `requires` section removing unit name from `contains` section.

How to find out which package the unit belongs to if I have no `*.pas` files, but only `*.bpl` and `*.dcu`?

Comment: From the message you've provided, the package relies upon those units. If you want to remove the dependencies, you need to remove the references. Perhaps you have a package in the requires clause that does not need to be there? Without seeing the source, it's hard to answer definitively

Answer (score 4):

Obviously your package uses a lot of units from a TeeChart package (or several packages? I don't know TeeChart very well). **Do not implicitly import them**, just put the *packages* your explicit units (i.e. the units you explicitly name in the `contains` section) need in the `requires` section.

Not only does that make your package a lot slimmer, it also avoids such naming conflicts. Anyone who uses your package will face a naming conflict when using other packages that contain units with the same name. That is why the IDE, recognizing that all or most of the packages the other package uses, are in your package, recommends linking to your package.

If your package did not contain these units, that wouldn't happen. That is why you should **always, really always, avoid having implicitly imported units**. If that happens, you get a warning (during compilation of the package). Heed it.

Example (package `MyControls`):

```
contains
  MyUnit;
```

and in `MyUnit`:

```
unit MyUnit;

uses
  TeeThis, TeeThat, TeeOther;
```

Now the `TeeThis`, `TeeThat` and `TeeOther` units are *implicitly* linked into your package. But if *your package* references the *other package* that contains these `TeeXXX` units (say, `TeeChart.bpl`), the compiler will not add them to your package, it will use them indirectly (*reference them*) from the `TeeChart` package. That makes your package smaller, and allows other packages to use the same `TeeXXX` units in the same way. There will be no naming conflict between your and other packages regarding the `TeeXXX` units.

```
requires
  TeeChart,
  etcetera;
```

Of course this puts on you the burden to ensure that everyone who uses your package will have the TeeChart package too, if necessary by distributing that package too (assuming licenses allow that).

### UPDATE

Your update shows that you now have the TeeChart packages in your requires. If the message is correct, the compiler also includes the units `TeeBlockCanvas`, `TeeMesh`, `TeeBlockEditor`, `TeeBlockGallery`, `TeeBlockClasses`, etc.etc. in *your* package, so the units you explicitly include (in the `contains`section) seem to use these units too. Put the packages that contain these units (probably `TeePro923`, `TeeUI923` and `Tee923`) in the `requires` section too:

```
requires
  rtl,
  vcl,
  vclx,
  // etc...
  TeePro923,
  TeeUI923,
  Tee923,
  TeeImage923,
  TeeGL923,
  // etc...
```

Now you should not get the message, that all those units were implicitly included into your package, anymore.

Comment: @Paul: no, it means exactly what I wrote: your *explicitly* imported units (e.g. `MyUnit`, the ones explicitly mentioned in the `contains`section) *use* units (like `TeeThis`, etc.) that are not explicitly imported, but because they are needed, are pulled, one by one, into the package anyway, so your package contains `MyUnit`as well as the three implicitly imported ones (`TeeThis`, etc.). See here: http://rvelthuis.blogspot.de/2017/08/implicitly-imported-units-in-package.html

Comment: In other words: your package contains all the units you wrote *as well as* all the units mentioned in the message, i.e. some thirty or so TeeChart units. That is wrong. Your package should only contain your units and only *reference* the other units from the `TeeChart`package by putting `TeeChart`in the `requires` section. You are telling the package to only link to the external units in that other package, instead of silently physically including them into your package.

Comment: Show your contains and requires section and I'll tell you what to change.

Comment: The units you wrote, i.e. those in the `contains` section have other TeeChart units in their `uses` clauses. These units are then put in *your* package, while they should have been _referenced_ only from the TeeChart packages. See my update.

Comment: I'll first have to understand your answer. Fact is that units should never be in two packages at the same time. You should have referenced the package that contained the unit you use, as I wrote. The **only** way to use a unit from another package is to **reference** that package. Anything else is simply wrong.

Comment: @Paul: It is possible, but that doesn't mean you should do it. It only makes sense if there is absolutely no chance that a unit appears in two packages at the same time. But even then, I would advise against it. Simply don't do it, because there is always the chance of a possible name conflict later on. If you need a unit from another package, reference it.